# silver searcher ignore multiple directories

Tags: command-line, ag

using [The silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) how can I ignore multiple directories?

I tried `ag foo --ignore-dir dir1,dir2` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you can specify the argument multiple times

`ag foo --ignore-dir dir1 --ignore-dir dir2`

Answer (score 61):

You an also do this (without needing to repeat the flag):

```
ag foo --ignore-dir={dir1,dir2}
```

You need to use this format with more than one directory. Otherwise, if it's with just one directory, you'd need to provide a comma, like: `ag foo --ignore-dir={dir1,}`.

Comment: Make sure there is no space after the comma. I had issues with this.

Comment: You can also simply use `--ignore` instead of `--ignore-dir`