# How do I let silver searcher ignore certain sub-directories?

Tags: command-line, ag

How do I let silver searcher ignore certian sub-directories, in my case I want ag to search md format only and **ignore all** the `node_modules` directories, I tried what here [silver searcher ignore multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601233/silver-searcher-ignore-multiple-directories) said, but it did not work.

```
ag --md --ignore-dir={node_modules} foo
```

I searched the possible solution but found some old issues, e.g, [Ignore file in subdirectory not applied properly (opened in 2013)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/287) and this [New release? opened in 2021](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1457)

So can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers in the linked Q&A and when I first tried them I did not read the answers carefully, e.g. the highest score one

> if it's with just one directory, you'd need to **provide a comma**, like:
> ag foo --ignore-dir={dir1,}.

So `ag --md --ignore-dir={node_modules,} foo` works but `ag --md --ignore-dir={node_modules} foo` does **NOT** work. My bad!

Or I can just `ag --md --ignore node_modules foo`, as [here said](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md)

> --ignore-dir NAME: Alias for --ignore for compatibility with ack.